# Assigning legends to column chart in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 for (int i = 0; i < initialDataSource.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Series series = new Series();
        series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

        foreach (DataRow dr in initialDataSource.Rows)
        {

            string y = (string)dr[i];
            if (y != "0")
            {
                series.Points.AddXY(dr["date"].ToString(), y);
            }
        }
        Chart1.Series.Add(series);


    }

}
```

Using this code I am getting chart as series chart and chart type is column (with three colors). Now I want to add legends to this graph. How can I please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

-> give your Series-object a Name (series.Name = "myColumname"; .. or see example below)

-> assign a new Legend() object to your chart object (see second example)

---

**Answer with example:**

Using your code as base..

```
for (int i = 0; i < initialDataSource.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
    Series series = new Series();
    series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

    series.Name = initialDataSource.Columns[i].ColumnName;

    foreach (DataRow dr in initialDataSource.Rows)
    {

        string y = (string)dr[i];
        if (y != "0")
        {
            series.Points.AddXY(dr["date"].ToString(), y);
        }
    }
    Chart1.Series.Add(series);


  }
```

And, either before or after your data loop, doesn't matter:

```
Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());

// or, if you want to change the properties of your legend: 
// Legend myLegend = new Legend();
// Chart1.Legends.Add(myLegend);
```